# JWT with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, jwt

When i try to establish connection with JWT it dosent give me antyhing, im not sure what i do wrong as im not so familiar with JWT

Im not able to do anything on localhost:4000 as there is no connection

Do you guys have any suggestions?? thanks for the help:)

app.js

```
var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token){
    jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, 'SECRET_KEY', function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
      socket.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  }
  else {
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
  }    
  })
  .on('connection', function(socket) {
    // Connection now authenticated to receive further events

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        io.emit('message', message);
    });
})
```

chat.js

```
    const socket = io()
   
   const {token} = sessionStorage;

   socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    socket
      .on('authenticated', function () {
        //do other things
      })
      .emit('authenticate', {token}); //send the jwt
  


    });
```

Comment: In the code you provided, there is a potential issue with the io.use() function, which is used to authenticate the socket connection using a JWT. If the io object is not defined, this could cause the connection to be closed before it is established.

Comment: @FreddyNoNose i've updated the code, forgot to add that part, do you still think thats where it fails?

Comment: I was able to make connection before adding the JWT part

Answer (score 1):

The token must be sent in the `auth` payload:

```js
const { token } = sessionStorage;
const socket = io({
  auth: {
    token
  }
});
```

This value can then be found on the server side:

```js
io.use((socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.auth.token;
  jwt.verify(token, 'SECRET_KEY', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    socket.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  });
});
```

Reference: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#auth